# Using rCharts to create Histogram

Tags: r, histogram, rcharts

I am trying unsucesfully to create a histogram using `nPlot` from rCharts. My data have the following format:

```
> head(Data)
   X       Date Age Race Sex         region
 1 1 2013-12-31  54 <NA>   M     washington
 2 2 2013-12-31  20 <NA>   M     california
 3 3 2013-12-31  34    B   M north carolina
 4 4 2013-12-30  43    B   M   pennsylvania
 5 5 2013-12-30  31    W   F     california
 6 6 2013-12-29  43    W   M       colorado
```

Using ggplot2 (and doBy for summaryBy) :

```
cdat <- summaryBy(Age~Sex,data=Data,FUN=c(mean),na.rm=TRUE)
cdat <- cdat[-3,]
ggplot(Data,aes(x=Age,fill=Sex))+
geom_histogram(binwidth=.7, alpha=.8, position="identity")+
geom_vline(data=cdat, aes(xintercept=Age.mean,  colour=Sex),
           linetype="dashed", size=1)
```

And the output is a histogram grouped by `Sex`:

[image]

I want to create a similar figure using rCharts package. I tried the following but without success:

```
output$Histogram1 <- renderChart({
    Trial <- summaryBy(.~Age+Sex,data=Data,FUN=length)
    Histogram1 <- nPlot(x='Age',y='X.length',group='Sex',data=Trial,type='bar',dom='Histogram1')
    Histogram1$chart(margin = list(left = 100))
    return(Histogram1)
})
```

The code is inside the `server.R` script -> for a shiny app.

Answer (score 0):

try renderChart2 instead of renderChart if the code you have works outside the shiny app:

```
output$Histogram1 <- renderChart2({
Trial <- summaryBy(.~Age+Sex,data=Data,FUN=length)
Histogram1 <- nPlot(x='Age',y='X.length',group='Sex',data=Trial,type='bar',dom='Histogram1')
Histogram1$chart(margin = list(left = 100))
return(Histogram1)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the exact error that you are facing?

Also, I had some problems too when I was using `type="bar"` in `nPlot` function.

The way it was fixed was by using `type="multiBarChart"`

Hope that helps!

**Edit 1:**

Also, as @susacb has suggested, use renderChart2 instead of renderChart and remove the `dom` parameter.